# How to make Python not overwrite a SQLite entry

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sign-in/sign-out function for students. The problem is that if they sign in a third time on the same day the code is overwriting their previous time_out timestamp. How can I make it not replace the last time_out Timestamp if a student accidentally signs out a third time.

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
import time  # used for sleep command
​
conn = sqlite3.connect('attendance.db')
​
c = conn.cursor()
​
​
# def create_db():
#     c.execute("""CREATE TABLE students (
#                 first text,
#                 date text,
#                 status_in text,
#                 time_in text,
#                 status_out text,
#                 time_out text
#                 )""")
#     conn.commit()
#     conn.close()
​
​
# Check if name has a daily entry, if doesnt exist store time_in timestamp
# If a timestamp already exists on that day put an time_out timestamp
def check_if_in():
    person = input('Name of student checking IN/OUT: ')
    date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%m-%d-%y")
    c.execute('SELECT status_in FROM students '
              'WHERE first = ? AND date = ?', [person, date])
    conn.commit()
    result = c.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        status_in = 'IN'
        timestamp = time.strftime('%I:%M %p')
        day = datetime.date.today().strftime('%m-%d-%y')
        c.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, date, status_in, time_in) "
                  "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", [person, day, status_in, timestamp])
        conn.commit()
        check_if_in()
    else:
        c.execute("SELECT status_in FROM students "
                  "WHERE first = ? AND date = ?", [person, date])
        conn.commit()
        result2 = c.fetchone()
        convert = ''.join(map(str, result2))
        if convert == 'IN':
            timestamp = time.strftime('%I:%M %p')
            c.execute("UPDATE students SET status_out = 'OUT' "
                      "WHERE first = ? and date = ?", [person, date])
            c.execute("UPDATE students SET time_out = ? "
                      "WHERE first = ? and date = ?", [timestamp, person, date])
            conn.commit()
            check_if_in()
        else:
            print('This will direct somewhere else')
​
​
check_if_in()
#create_db()
```

Comment: In the same way you check for an already existing sign in you can check for an existing sign out and don't overwrite it if present.

Comment: If there is ever a situation where a student might legitimately sign in or out multiple times per day, you should store the sign-ins and sign-outs in a separate table. Then you can very easily support any number of sign-ins and sign-outs.

Comment: @kindall very good suggestion

Comment: I see many problems with your approach/code, such as one function trying to do everything despite its name which is supposed to only check (but inserts and updates).  "Divide and conquer."  An action table should be used to keep track of Student_ID, date-time, and direction (IN or OUT).  Only INSERT into that table.  Never UPDATE previous actions or lose history.  A query can give you the status of a student at any given time.  Solve the problem first at the SQL level, i.e., correct database schema, queries, etc. and then write Python or whatever other language code to deal with it.

Comment: @tonypdmtr where can I read up on action tables? I Googled them, but the results were broad.

Comment: @TonyRodriguez I simply meant a table for keeping student activity, as in IN or OUT, you can name it whatever.  Nothing specific.

Comment: @tonypdmtr ah ok gotcha. Thanks.